# Display GIF image on hover jquery, nothing happens

Tags: jquery, html5-video, gif

Ok, I have a video centered, which shows a loop of an eye opening and closing. behind that I have an hidden div which contains a GIF of the eye closeing. What I want to archieve is that when the user hovers a button the GIF is shown above the video. This is what I have so far:

jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    <script language="text/javascript">
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = "eye.gif";
        $("#apDiv1").hover(function () {

          $("#gif").show().attr('src', image.src);
        }, function(){
            $("#gif").hide();
        });
      </script>
```

HTML button:

```
<div id="apDiv1">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="../designcompany/index.html">
                                    <span class="ca-icon">Mode</span>
                                    </a>                    
                                </li>
                            </div>
```

HTML movie and GIF:

```
<div id="w">


    <img id="gif" src="eye.gif"/>
                                    <div id="videoplayer">
                                        <center>
                                            <video id="intro" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" autobuffer="autobuffer" muted="muted" width="1024" height="400" >
                                            <source src="./media/eye.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                            </video>
                                        </center>   
                                    </div>
                            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#gif{
 display:none;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element "on top" of another element, you have to set it's z-index to a higher number.

Comment: z-index is not the issue here... it's about centering the image (CSS) on top of the video, try his code and you'll see...

Answer (score 0):

*What I want to archieve is that when the user hovers a button the GIF is shown above the video*

```
 $("#apDiv1").hover(
          function () {
           $("#gif").show().attr('src', image.src);
           $('#gif').css('z-index','999999');
           $('#videoplayer').css('z-index','999');
          },

          function(){
           $("#gif").hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    <script language="text/javascript">
        //your code is here
    </script>
</script>
```

That wont work, you need to close the first script tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       //your code now goes here
    });
</script>
```

And I think the language attribute was popular in the 1990's (about the same time center tags dissapeared) ?

Then you place the elements in the right order:

```
<div id="apDiv1">
    <div id="videoplayer" style="margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
        <video id="intro" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" autobuffer="autobuffer" muted="muted" width="1024" height="400">
            <source src="./media/eye.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <img id="gif" src="eye.gif" style="display: none; position: absolute; top:0; left:0;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And hide and show the image:

```
$("#apDiv1").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $("#gif").toggle(e.type==='mouseenter')
});
```